# How to query SQLite data hourly?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

The data table looks like the following:

```
ID DATE 
 1 2020-12-31 10:10:00
 2 2020-12-31 20:30:00
 3 2020-12-31 20:50:00
 4 2021-01-02 17:10:00
 5 2021-01-02 17:20:00
 6 2021-01-02 17:30:00
 7 2021-01-03 23:10:00
 ..
```

And I would like to query only the last entry per hour per day, and to have the resulte like:

```
ID DATE 
 1 2020-12-31 10:10:00
 3 2020-12-31 20:50:00
 6 2021-01-02 17:30:00
 7 2021-01-03 23:10:00
 ..
```

I tried to look for hourly query and found the following

> `strftime('%H', " + DATE + ", '+1 hours')`

However, not sure how to use it properly (e.g. with GROUP BY ? then how to ensure it takes the lastest entry of the hour), therefore, would be great to have some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
SELECT ID, DATE
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strftime('%Y%m%d%H', DATE) ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
  FROM tablename  
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Instead of `strftime('%Y%m%d%H', DATE)` you could also use `substr(DATE, 1, 13)`.

For versions of SQLite previous to 3.25.0 which do not support window functions you can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE strftime('%Y%m%d%H', t2.DATE) = strftime('%Y%m%d%H', t1.DATE)
    AND t2.DATE > t1.DATE  
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=158a268b056678a9ae14f2c8aac912a1).
Results:

```
> ID | DATE               
> -: | :------------------
>  1 | 2020-12-31 10:10:00
>  3 | 2020-12-31 20:50:00
>  6 | 2021-01-02 17:30:00
>  7 | 2021-01-03 23:10:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This works when testing them outside android, but when using android.database.sqlite API, I got syntax error: 

Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database. 
(near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ID, DATE FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strftime('%Y%m%d%H', DATE) ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn FROM tablename) WHERE rn = 1 ORDER BY ID) 

Not sure what goes wrong and I suspect that it's due to android.

Comment: @user3442437 Android uses old versions of SQLite that do not support window functions like ROW_NUMBER(). I will edit with another query that you can use in a few mins.

Comment: may I have another quick question? - if I have a third column with an int number, and I want to select the row which has the largest number of that hour, to achieve so, I have tried: [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=31257dc460bce0034b954dda82360f21), but it shows two rows with the same hour and number, how do I avoid that? @forpas

Comment: @user3442437 you mean that you want the row with the latest date for each hour but if there are 2 rows with that latest date you want only the row with the largest number?

Comment: correct, I want the row with the largest number of each hour. In other words, one row per hour with the largest number @forpas

Comment: @user3442437 for the example in that link which ids do you want returned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227048/discussion-between-user3442437-and-forpas).